# How to speed up Magento 2 Website?

Tags: magento2, seo, ecommerce-tracking

How to speed up Magento 2 Website? - What are the effective checklist for it?

Comment: Magento is slow by default

Comment: https://servebolt.com/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/

Comment: Speed up Magento 2 check Optimization Guide.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_perf-optimize.html

Comment: [How to speed up Magento 2 Website - An effective checklist](https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/blog/magento-blog-56/post/how-to-speed-up-magento-2-website-an-effective-checklist-446)

Comment: https://elogic.co/blog/speed-up-magento-2-store/

Answer (score 1):

1. Inspect Server and System Requirements;
2. Htaccess settings;
3. Use built-in profiler;
4. Using Varnish cache;
5. Speed up Checkout process;
6. MySQL configuration optimization;
7. Enable CDN;
8. Change to Production mode;
9. Enable Javascript bundling;
10. Merge/Minify CSS and Js Files;
11. Enable flat products and categories;
12. Always use latest version of Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to improve the page speed.

- Enable GZIP compression.
- Use Lazy Loading for images.
- Keep your Magento and 3rd party extensions up to date. Use sprite image instead
  of separate images of small icons.

I hope the above tip will useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all cache types are enabled (`bin/magento cache:status` and `bin/magento cache:enable` if they're disabled). It's faster to flush the cache types everytime you make changes than to have them disabled.

When you're ready to publish your site put it in production mode (`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`). This will generate classes and deploy static content - please note that it's hard to make changes (js and css) after this so don't do it unless you're done.

Before going into production mode enable css and js minifying and merging and js bundling (see Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer section); please note that this is only visible in developer mode.

Optimize images (I recommend using https://tinyjpg.com/), refractor your code:

- make sure you don't use nested `foreach` loops
- *never* load model entites in loops (`$product = $this->_product->load($item->getId())` or something like that)
- search throough your layout xml files and make sure there are no blocks with `cacheable="false"` since this disables caching for the entire page where it is rendered (read more here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html)

This is what came out of my mind, hope it helps you :)

Comment: Also update your Magento to 2.2.6, it's supposed to be faster although I'm yet to test that :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to speed up magento 2 website follow below steps.

Steps to Optimize Performance.

```
Step 1) Enable Flat Categories and Products
Step 2) Merge CSS and JS Files
Step 3) Content Delivery Network
Step 4) Caching
Step 5) Image Optimization
Step 6) Enable Compression
Step 7) Reduce Server Response Time
Step 8) Magento Updates
```

Hope this help!